Workflow not triggering on pull request
I tried to make a GitHub Actions workflow to launch commands on my server when I'm doing a pull request from any development branch into the uat branch.
My script seems to contains everything it needs, the SSH key is saved on the account and everything, but when I'm doing a pull request nothing triggers, even if the test and the uat branches both have the workflows saved in the .github/workflows directory.
Here is my workflow:
name: Test Branch on PR to UAT

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - uat

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup SSH
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Run script on server
        env:
          TEST_BRANCH: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
        run: |
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myhostname@myipaddress << 'EOF'
            here I put my ssh commands
          EOF

I saw on another post that the issue might be that I need to use pull_request_target, but I'm not sure.
